# Make workspace bar always popped out

Tags: 18.04, gnome, workspace-switcher

In ubuntu 18.04, when you click `Activities` the workspace bar is in the right but you need to hover over it to see it. Is there a way to keep it popped out(/unhide it)?

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ and search for "workspace" and you'll find a number of GNOME extensions that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Done that. In case anyone ended up here, I used expand workspaces switcher from here https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1351/show-workspaces/. Hope this helps.